# SQL Dates Selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I Have a OPL_Dates Table with Start Date and End Dates as Below:

```
dbo.OPL_Dates
ID       Start_date       End_date
--------------------------------------
12345    1975-01-01       2001-12-31
12345    1989-01-01       2004-12-31
12345    2005-01-01       NULL
12345    2007-01-01       NULL
12377    2009-06-01       2009-12-31
12377    2013-02-07       NULL
12377    2010-01-01       2012-01-01
12489    2011-12-31       NULL
12489    2012-03-01       2012-04-01
```

The Output I am looking for is:

```
ID       Start_date       End_date
-------------------------------------
12345    1975-01-01       2004-12-31
12345    2005-01-01       NULL
12377    2009-06-01       2009-12-31
12377    2010-01-01       2012-01-01
12377    2013-02-07       NULL
12489    2011-12-31       NULL
```

Basically, I want to show the gap between the OPL periods(IF Any) else I need min of Start Date and Max of End Dates, for a particular ID.NULL means Open-Ended Date which can be converted to "9999-12-31".

Comment: gaps where there is no adjacent null rows?

Comment: add bounty and provide all scenarios

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Thanks For the Reply,I din't completely get your Question but , start and End dates for every ID if there is a gap in his period. For 12345 I want his Start date which is 1975-01-01 and his end date which is 2004-12-31 because the start date 1989-01-01 is already covered in the above time period and then the start date 2005-01-01 to end date "NULL" as the start date 2007-01-01 also falls under the time period 2005-01-01  through NULL.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I've added an other scenario. Please take a look. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49970626/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it, because without that we cannot help. Also please see **[ask]**.

Answer (score 1):

The following pretty much does what you want:

```
with p as (
      select v.*, sum(inc) over (partition by v.id order by v.dte) as running_inc
      from t cross apply
           (values (id, start_date, 1),
                   (id, coalesce(end_date, '2999-12-31'), -1)
           ) v(id, dte, inc)
     )
select id, min(dte), max(dte)
from (select p.*, sum(case when running_inc = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by dte desc) as grp
      from p
     ) p
group by id, grp;
```

Note that it changes the "inifinite" end date from `NULL` to 2999-12-31.  This is a convenience, because `NULL` orders first in SQL Server ascending sorts.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/13878) is a SQL Fiddle.

What is this doing?  It is unpivoting the dates into a single column, with a 1/-1 flag (`inc`) indicating whether the record is a start or end.  The running sum of this flag then indicates the groups that should be combined.  When the running sum is 0, then a group has ended.  To include the end date in the right group, a reverse running sum is needed -- but that's a detail.